# Android Studio 2.1.1 - Problema de Renderização

Tags: android, android-studio

Meu Android Studio 2.1.1 (Windows XP) está dando problema ao ser aberto: a tela do celular virtual está cinza, em vez de branca. Com isso, qualquer item que eu venha a inserir no meu projeto fica invisível.
[image: Meu projeto no Android Studio logo após ele ser aberto]

Answer (score 1):

Eu mesmo encontrei a solução:

Clique no botão “AppTheme”, localizado acima da pré-visualização, e na caixa de diálogo “Select Theme”, escolha outro tema pro app: “Material Dark”, “Material Light”, “Holo Dark”, Holo Light" etc.